# Install Eclipse incremental Java compiler on Ubuntu without installing Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javac

Is there a way to install the Eclipse incremental Java compiler on Ubuntu without installing Eclipse? Or if I install Eclipse, is there a command line command to run the incremental compiler that I can use independent of Eclipse?

Comment: Looks like this compiler is OSS and available in Intellij too? I am looking to be able to run it manually from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is known as 'ecj' and the standalone version is known as the 'ecj batch compiler' or 'JDT core batch compiler'.

The batch compiler is available as a separate download on the [Eclipse Project Downloads](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) page - choose the release you want and search for 'JDT Core Batch Compiler'.

The Eclipse documentation covers use of the compiler on the [Using the batch compiler](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm) page. In its simplest form this is just

```
java -jar ecj.jar -classpath rt.jar A.java
```

Comment: yeah i wonder if it will watch files or if you need to tell it when files change. thats the next step for me.

Comment: No it won't watch. It is just a replacement for javac.

Comment: I got the ecj.jar file, thanks. What's the rt.jar that you mentioned?

Comment: Looks like `rt.jar` is all the core classes for java, I suppose those are also included in a build for most maven projects

Comment: hi @greg-449 I got this compiler to work, but it doesn't seem to be incremental - what I am looking for is a compiler that can hold current files in memory and listen for changed file paths and then compile those - does this exist?

Comment: That isn't how the Eclipse incremental build system works so, no, you can't do that with ecj. Incremental building in Eclipse is driven by the core Eclipse resource change and incremental build systems. This only works for resources in the workspace.

Comment: Well I wouldn't be using the Batch Compiler with Eclipse (workspace pertains to Eclipse right?), I would be using it standalone with some other folder structure etc

Comment: Neither ecj or the full Eclipse is going to do that.

Comment: Yeah, there must be a way to do this with a Java compiler? It can't be that hard given that it's interpreted. There must be some java dev compiler that can hold the .class files in memory and new .java files are compiled with those .class files instead of re-reading all files and re-compiling everything.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I don't see how interpretation is relevant to this question. I wonder if you want to re-implement the IDE (in a headless way perhaps) with its full fledged support for incremental compilation? Without more context I can't see where you're heading.

Answer (score 0):

yeah i am looking through docs, ideally find some sort of tcp or http mechanism to send batch compilation process a path to a changed file. i am not even sure if the batch compiler works as a server at all.. t my original impression was that it will build incrementally, it just needs to know about changes? i am hoping for something like `tsc --watch` for TypeScript.